# can I setup two LANs (each w/their own WAN) to share the other's WAN

Tags: networking, router, wan

I have a networking question for the experts here. Please let me know if there's a better place for me to seek help.

LAN1 is a house in a rural area with slow ADSL internet. LAN2 is an "observatory" building 420 meters away housing a telescope. Observatory has Verizon 4G modem that works quite well.

If I setup something like a Ubiquiti point to point radio link between the two, can I configure the networks to:

- load balance internet access between the two WANs
- share files between LANs
- remote desktop between LANs
- (edit) if not load balance, then failover to the other WAN
- (edit) avoid unnecessary traffic on the radio link

The top half of [this illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8rtO.jpg) depicts how it's setup now. The bottom half depicts what I'm imagining.

I would be willing to purchase new routers for this purpose.

Suggestions? Advice?

Thank you!

Barnett

Comment: *load balance internet access between the two WANs* It is posible, but too hard - you need to create a server in combined LAN which will act as a gateway and will send the connections via 1st or 2nd WAN depending on the channels loading (and maybe another rules - protocol, destination address, etc.). *share files between LANs, remote desktop between LANs* Yes. But for addresses stability you'll need to disable router's DHCPs and use DHCP on inter-LAN router node. And for to "see" the stations from another LAN in "My Network" you'll need to run WINS server service on it additionally.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! If the gateway on the combined LAN is at house, then would outbound (to WAN) observatory traffic always traverse the radio link? If I must abandon load balancing, can I fail-over to the other WAN? Could I configure to force SONOS to always use the observatory WAN? Is there a resource you might suggest that I study to understand this better?

Comment: @barnett The sharing of files is easy, and whereas normally TUN is recommended in OpenVPN, a TAP setup would likely be best for your scenario, as it would transparently route traffic and each router would be on the same subnet, but if you want a subnet separate from each router's own subnet that both would share, then a TUN setup would be recommended.